# Way to optimize this middleware code / make shorter

Tags: laravel

I want to improve in the code I write, I tried several things but this one seems to be the least worst, but I have the feeling that it is not optimized at all, lots of code repetition.

Do you have any ideas for optimization ? This is a middleware to check if user is ban or inactive

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check())  {

            if (auth()->user()->isBanned()) {
                auth()->logout();
                $request->session()->invalidate();
                $request->session()->regenerateToken();

                return redirect()->route('auth.login')->with('error', trans('login.banned'));
            }

            if(auth()->user()->isInactive()) {
                auth()->logout();
                $request->session()->invalidate();
                $request->session()->regenerateToken();

                return redirect()->route('auth.login')->with('error', trans('login.inactive'));
            }
        }



        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Not really a SO question, but the two if statements are the same, apart from the string in your `trans()` function. You can make it shorter by using a variable & only changing that variable. is that needed, nope.

Comment: It's true that I hesitated before posting it on SO. Otherwise you have to be careful not to make a too unreadable code to save lines, it seems ok even if it's true that there is some repetition? I'm right?

Comment: Move repeat code into a private function. Repeating is never okay.

Comment: Ok user3532758, i'm gonna do this, you right

Comment: @user3532758 Repeating code CAN be ok if it improves readability... Depends what you repeat, and how much you repeat.

Comment: @GertB. while this may lead into a pit of opinion based argument, I would like to ask: readability?

Comment: @user3532758 Readable code, easy to read, easy to understand. If you have to write complex if statements to prevent 3 simple lines of repeated code... . But thats an opinion.

Comment: @GertB. to me complex if statements are never okay either. But, what I meant is how does repeating code improve readability? If you had said repeating once or twice is ok if its a simple piece of code/application, then that's easy to get behind. But I fail to understand a situation where repeating improves readability. And I would say DRYing helps you avoid complex if statements, if anything. Most of all, repeating = difficulty maintaining.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to be fine, except the `invalidate` and `regenerateToken` which aren't necessary.

First of all, you must cache both `isBanned` and `isInactive` at least for a few seconds/minutes, so you don't call the database on every single request.

The second thing, is to split them into two different middlewares:

- `DenyIfUserBanned`.
- `DenyIfUserInactive`.

---

Another way is to emit an event when a user gets banned, but this will only work in sessions with the database driver, so you can remove the user from the `sessions` table by an its id.

Comment: You are totally right. I will add a first condition that will check in the cache (with Cache::())? if they are present or not, if not I call the database. Is this it?

Comment: great suggestions.

Comment: I just don't see how the cache works with a banned user?
I have a status that changes to 2 when I click on a ban button, it's a permanent ban. I have to cache the fact that this user is banned? for how long?

Comment: @Kylian You cache the user status and the cache name can be `user_{user_id}_status`. And when you change user status any where in your app, you need to update that cache value. Simple as it is.

Comment: Just one last question, where do you cache the current user's status? I hesitate between several places

Comment: @Kylian Create an observer `php artisan make:observer User --model=User` and then cache the user status whenever it gets updated, something smilar to this: `Cache::put('user_status_'.$user->id, $user->isBanned());`; BE CAREFUL, executing `php artisan cache:clear` clears the entire cache, hence all the user statues will be lost.